# Thymeleaf-Unable to add a logo to email

Tags: html, thymeleaf, jhipster

I'm currently working on an email template with Thymeleaf and JHipster. I'm trying to add a logo image. I tried many methods, but I'm confused, where to save images and how to add them to html template of the email.
I used `th:src=@{/logo.png}` tag and my images are located inside `project-web-app\src\main\webapp\logo.png`.

Comment: Which version of JHipster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of your image should point to an absolute URL with hostname that can be reached by mail reader.

In JHipster, this URL can be configured in `application*.yml` in `jhipster.mail.base-url` property. You can see it being used in `src/main/resources/templates/mail/activationEmail.html` for registration link.

In your case, your template should refer to your image like this: `th:src="@{|${baseUrl}/logo.png|}"`.

Answer (score 1):

Images are static resources. Thymeleaf (Spring Boot) loads static resources from the class-path and from org.webjars. Static resources should be located in src/main/resources/static folder.

Example structure:

```
  myProject
  - src
    -main
      - java
      - resources
        - static
          - css
            - style.css
          - img
            - logo.png
          - js
        - templates
          - home.html
```

Typically in a spring boot application, you can ignore static resource location configurations, because it’s done automatically. But you can customize static resources loading, using the following configuration.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**", "/img/**", "/css/**", "/js/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/", "classpath:/static/img/", "classpath:/static/css/", "classpath:/static/js/");
    }
}
```