# How use bootstrap with thymleaf in jhipster application

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf, jhipster

I'm currently working on an email template with thymeleaf in a jhipster application.

My problem is that i can't use  bootstrap css  in thymeleaf template.

I understand that thymeleaf is a server-side technology and cannot load bootstrap css that exists on client-side (via node_modules), but when i saw answers to these two questions [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867321/thymeleaf-unable-to-add-a-logo-to-the-email) and [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420593/send-email-with-images-using-jhipster-and-thymeleaf) i tried by similarty to import my css like this

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"  th:href="@{|${baseUrl}/content/css/global.css|}" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"  th:href="@{|${baseUrl}/content/css/vendor.css|}" />
```

but thymleaf still can't load this two files, i have no errors on console but css classes (bootstrap and mine) are just ignored.

**PS : global.css contains my css classes, and vendor.css is the default jhipster file that calls bootstrap**
**vendor.css**

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
@import '~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
```

My template is located under

```
/src/main/resources/mails/applicationReport.html
```

My css is located under

```
/src/main/webapp/content/css/vendor.css
/src/main/webapp/content/css/global.css
```

So how can i use  css classes from global.css and vendor.css in thymleaf?

**UPDATE**
After Gaël Marziou's answser i added these two lines to /demain/webpack/webpack.common.js

```
 { from: './src/main/webapp/content/css/global.css', to: 'global.css' },
 { from: './src/main/webapp/content/css/vendor.css', to: 'vendor.css' },
```

and in /src/main/resources/mails/applicationReport.html i call these two files like that

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"  th:href="@{|${baseUrl}/global.css|}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"  th:href="@{|${baseUrl}/vendor.css|}" />
```

but Thymleaf stills ignore my css classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS files are bundled by webpack, so content/css/global.css does not exist in your built webapp and cannot be accessed by URL, check it by unzipping your war file.

However, you could have both bundled stylesheets and original css files in your war file by adding these files to the configuration of `CopyWebpackPlugin` see in `webpack-common.js` file.

Comment: Have you checked that the war file contains global.css and vendor.css files? What is the link in mail message as received? Have you tried this link in a browser? Have you read about mail readers limitations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105963/can-you-link-to-a-css-file-from-an-email?