# Problem to load external CSS in thymeleaf while creating the template for Email service

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, jakarta-mail, jhipster

I'm using JHipster and searching for an example of templating emails with Thymleaf. My problem is that the CSS and JS (static files) aren't injected into my templates..

```
<link href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
       rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
```

I am getting the following error:

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Link base "/css/Boostrap.min.css" cannot be context relative (/) or page relative unless you implement the org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext interface

Below is my Spring boot resource structure :

```
--- resources
     |--- i18n
     |--- mails
     |--- static
           |--- css
                 |--- boostrap.min.css
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Try to rename bootstrap.min.css to bootstrap.css

Comment: I try this combination, but its a problem of injection

Comment: Have you seen this issue? It looks like your problem

Comment: Yeah I have tried it but its not working , same error

Comment: I forgot the link: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleafexamples-springmail/issues/2

Comment: is your template folder is under resources? and you have your email template under it??

Answer (score 1):

Your message template should refer to absolute external URL of your CSS with domain name, it should not use relative URL. If you don't do so the mail reader does not know where to download this CSS from.

This is why there is `jhipster.mail.base-url` property in `application-prod.yml`

The generated templates already use it for favicon:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" th:href="@{|${baseUrl}/favicon.ico|}" />
```

I would add that external CSS could be blocked by mail readers depending on users settings especially when not using https and there's nothing you can do against it. This is why most people will recommend inlining styles rather than linking to external stylesheets. Styling in HTML mail is hard and you will find many resources explaining why  and how to workaround some of these issues. View the source of HTML mails you received in your inbox to get an idea.

Comment: I have tried it before, but css is not applying to html. 
I also check your previous asnwer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48195776/how-use-bootstrap-with-thymleaf-in-jhipster-application
But I am unable to configure it

Answer (score 1):

For Email templates apparently you have to remove the preceding "/"

```
<link href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css" th:href="@{css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
```